# Magento connect manager redirects to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

I am facing the issue of when I click on Magento Connect Manager it redirects to the homepage of my site with the URL:

www.mysite.com/?return=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mysite.com%252Findex.php%252F12345abc%252F

My permission settings for downloader/index.php is 644 with version 1.9.1.0 installed. I have:

- Downloaded a fresh copy and reinstalled downloader to my store root directory
- Deleted my var/cache and var/sessions
- Deleted connect.cfg and cache.cfg from downloader folder

I've tried all suggestions I could find but none of them seem to work. Any help one this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to install extension ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to install an extension, so I updated to version 1.9.2.4 and downloader started working again. However the funny thing is I stopped installing extensions in downloader and install them directly through FTP, problem solved.

Comment: good job buddy.....